# Find maximum value of a attribute in a list of custom objects using lamdaj

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am trying to figure out a way to get the maximum value of an attribute and its object reference from a `list` containing custom objects.

Below is my code and I am supposed to use `java 8 lambda expressions` here. I am not allowed to use any of the google guava libraries.

My question is how can I determine whether the `sequenceNumber` attribute from `CcarReportPreferenceConfig` objects is in a list.

The sequence number will be like `1 or 2 or 3 or 4`. If I have 5 objects of `CcarReportPreferenceConfig` and if each objects sequence number is like `1,2,3,4,5` I need to determine that `5` is the largest of all

```
List<CcarReportPreferenceConfig> ccarReportPreferenceConfigs = ccarReportPrefConfigMapper.ccarReportPrefConfigDTOsToCcarReportPrefConfigs(ccarReportPrefConfigDTOList);
for (CcarReportPreferenceConfig ccarReportPreferenceConfig : ccarReportPreferenceConfigs) {
   if (ccarReportPreferenceConfig.getSequenceNumber().intValue() == 1) {
       ccarReportPreferenceConfig.setRejectSequence("DQM");
   } else if (ccarReportPreferenceConfig.getSequenceNumber()==LargestNumber){
       ccarReportPreferenceConfig.setRejectSequence("DQM");
   } else {
       ccarReportPreferenceConfig.setRejectSequence("S2");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MaxFromAList {

    int sequence = 0;
    String code = "";

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public MaxFromAList(int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    public int getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<MaxFromAList> list = new ArrayList<MaxFromAList>();
        list.add(new MaxFromAList(1111));
        list.add(new MaxFromAList(2));
        list.add(new MaxFromAList(654643));
        list.add(new MaxFromAList(41));
        list.add(new MaxFromAList(500));

        list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(MaxFromAList::getSequence))
            .ifPresent(max -> max.setCode("MAXCODE"));

        list.stream().filter(i -> !i.getCode().equals("MAXCODE")).forEach(ele -> setIdentificationCode(ele));


        printMyList(list);
    }

    public static void setIdentificationCode(MaxFromAList element){
        switch (element.sequence){
            case 1:
                element.setCode("DQM");break;
            default:
                element.setCode("");
        }
    }

    public static void printMyList(List<MaxFromAList> mylist){
        mylist.stream().forEach( o -> System.out.println("Sequence : " + o.sequence + "  Code : "+ o.getCode()));
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to write `(a,b) -> { return expression; }`, a simple `(a,b) -> expression` is enough. Anyway, you save even more typing (and repeating yourself) by using the factory method `Comparator.comparing(o -> o.sequence)` rather than `(first, second)->{ return (first.sequence > second.sequence)? 1 : (first.sequence == second.sequence)? 0 : -1; }`…

Comment: @Holger thanks for your pinpoint. `Comparator#comparing`. Appreciate it :)

Comment: @Holger I am pretty new to Java 8.Could you please recitfy and incorporate your feed back in the code please. That would be of great help to me :)

Comment: @Balaji I updated answer considering _Holger's_ comment

Comment: @SergeyLagutin thank you so much.  Also another question is here is we are tweaking by setting the maxvalue's object's maxcode to be MAXCODE. Isnt there a way to live without it.If I use a comparator in my class and sort it then the list will contain the highest object at index 0. Is there a way to do in Java 8 lamda as well without setting or modifying attribute's value

Comment: @Balaji `Stream#max` returns max element. just process it as you want.

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Thank you and the same to other guys who helped me here as well.Beyond Optional , I am learning something around Streams now